# Spring boot actuator endpoints.sensitive stop working in newer version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have following warning in code when set property **endpoints.sensitive** when setting it in spring boot version 2.0.0.M4. How I can configure it now?

Answer (score 0):

> By default, actuator endpoints are exposed on the same port that
>   serves regular HTTP traffic. Take care not to accidentally expose
>   sensitive information if you change the management.security.enabled
>   property.

For 2.0.0.M4: [Securing endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M4/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-security)

Comment: actually it's a docmentation snippet. But I need something how to avoid that.

Comment: Might be trying to use property `management.security.enabled` instead `endpoints.sensitive` ?